# Limit with log and trig functions using L'Hopitals rule

Tags: calculus, limits

Could anyone tell me if this is correct?

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{2x}-\pi^{x}}{sin(3x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2e^{2x}-\pi^{x} ln(\pi)}{3cos(3x)} = \frac{2e^{2(0)}-\pi^{(0)} ln(\pi)}{3cos(3(0))} = \frac{2\cdot 1-0}{3\cdot1} = \frac{2}{3} $$

I'm getting a bit of a different result on [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20to%200%20%28e%5E%282x%29-pi%5Ex%29/sin%283x%29)

If it's incorrect, mind telling me where I went wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\log(\pi) \neq 0$. You need not resort to L'Hospital's rule for this limit. You can get it from first principles.
$$\dfrac{e^{2x} - \pi^x}{\sin(3x)} = \dfrac{3x}{\sin(3x)} \times \dfrac{(e^{2x} - 1) - (\pi^x-1)}{3x}\\
= \dfrac{3x}{\sin(3x)} \times \left(\dfrac{e^{2x} - 1}{2x} \times \dfrac23 - \dfrac{e^{x\log(\pi)}-1}{x \log(\pi)} \times \dfrac{\log(\pi)}{3} \right)$$
Now recall the following limits
$$\lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(y)}{y} = 1$$
$$\lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{e^{y}-1}{y} = 1$$
Hence, you get the limit as
$$1 \times \left( 1 \times \dfrac23 - 1 \times \dfrac{\log(\pi)}3\right) = \dfrac{2 - \log(\pi)}3$$

Comment: Ouch..I don't know why I assumed \pi^0 would be zero. Thanks for the thorough explanation I learnt from it. :)

Comment: It would seem that L'hopital would be easier and a lot more straightforward.

Comment: @Mike For L'Hopital, you need additional machinery like derivatives etc, which in turn rely on the limits from first principles. If a problem is easier from first principles, then I prefer that way as opposed to L'Hopital.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:
$$\pi^0\ln(\pi)\neq0$$